# While reading about linked lists from a book I got stuck at two lines

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
struct list{
    char data;
    list *next;
    }
    void main(){
    list *start,node1,node2;
    //below two lines got me
    start=(struct list*)malloc(sizeof(list));     //Dynamic allocation of memory of size list whose address is stored in start
    start=&node1;       // start holds the address of node1 which is not dynamically allocated .
```

I don't understand why is *start given a dynamic address if the second statement overrides it by giving it the memory address of node1 which is in the stack(atlest what I understood). Anyone please help.

Please explain me why is *start initialized in two ways, dynamically and statically ?

Comment: If that is in the book, the book is bad. You´re right, it´s nonsense code.

Comment: It's just demonstrating the syntax of the two forms. It's not meant as a real program

Comment: The code looks like C but is invalid: it's missing a crucial semicolon, and it uses `void` as return type for `main`. When these up-front errors are corrected it's nonsense. Burn the book.

Comment: Echo Alf. Burn this book. Its not a good C book and it definitely will not be a good C++ book.

Answer (score 2):

My first reaction: If you read that, throw away the book.

My second reaction: If they are just showing different valid ways of setting the pointer, then it's ok - we don't have enough context to know though.

Basically you are correct - as written the code is bad. You lose track of the malloced memory (so it leaks).

Comment: Same thing I was thinking, that maybe it was an example of another way to set the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that is a confusing sample code, maybe it was trying to demo something like this,

```
void main(){
    list *start_d,*start_s,node1,node2;

    start_d = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(list));//Dynamic allocation of memory of size list whose address is stored in start

    start_s = &node1;// start holds the address of node1 which is not dynamically allocated .

    if(starts_d)
        free(start_d);
}
```

Comment: That's not really much better. If it is supposed to be model code it is lacking in several points.